# How to do many small changes in big string in fastest way. Visual C++

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli

I tried to deal with this problem over month. I need to do many replacements (over 10 millions) in one big string (String ^). Also I need to do it fast. My way was correctly but program was running over 30 minutes.

Problem:
I have a table of changes to do: `[strWas1, strWillBe1, strWas2, strWillBe2, ..., strWas10^7, strWillBe10^7]`. Also I have one big string which can contain some of `strWasN` but it also can contain `something-elsestrWas1` and I don't want to change it because "`something-elsestrWas1`" is not "`strWas1`".

For example String is:

> "I have two dogs, three notdogs, also dogsikong, 5dogs, -dogs. DOGS,
>   Dogs, DoGs, 33DoGs00"

Now I need to change all isolated "dogs" from letters ("dogs" is strWas1) to "cats" ("cats" is strWillBe1). Result should be:

> "I have two cats, three notdogs, also dogsikong, 5cats, -cats. cats,
>   cats, cats, 33cats00"

My last try was:

```
array<String^>^ strArray = gcnew array<String^>(9999999);
strArray[0] = gcnew String("dogs");
strArray[1] = gcnew String("cats");
//...
strArray[9999998] = gcnew String("whatReplace");
strArray[9999999] = gcnew String("newText");
bool found = false;
int index;
bool doThis = true;
String ^ notAllowed = u8"aąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoópqrsśtuvwxyzźżAĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPQRSŚTUVWXYZŹŻёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ";
String ^ text = u8"I have two dogs, three notdogs, also dogsikong, 5dogs, -dogs. DOGS, Dogs, DoGs, 33DoGs00";
for (int i = 0; i < 9999999; i+=2) {
    while (found = text->Contains(strArray[i])) {
        index = text->IndexOf(strArray[i]);
        MessageBox::Show(index.ToString());
        doThis = true;
        if (index == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < notAllowed->Length; j++) {
                if (text->Substring(strArray[i]->Length, 1) == notAllowed->Substring(j, 1)) doThis = false;
            }
        }
        else if (text->Length - index - strArray[i]->Length) {
            for (int j = 0; j < notAllowed->Length; j++) {
                if (text->Substring(index-1, 1) == notAllowed->Substring(j, 1)) doThis = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int j = 0; j < notAllowed->Length; j++) {
                if ((text->Substring(index - 1, 1) == notAllowed->Substring(j, 1)) || (text->Substring(index+strArray[i]->Length,1)== notAllowed->Substring(j, 1))) doThis = false;
            }
        }
        if (doThis) {
        text = text->Substring(0, index) + strArray[i + 1] + text->Substring(index + strArray[i]->Length, text->Length - index - strArray[i]->Length);
    }
    }
}
```

But this is working for endlessly

**New version (thanks to Vlad Feinstein):**

```
array<String^>^ strArray = gcnew array<String^>(10);
strArray[0] = gcnew String("dogs");
strArray[1] = gcnew String("cats");
strArray[2] = gcnew String("dogs");
strArray[3] = gcnew String("cats");
strArray[4] = gcnew String("dogs");
strArray[5] = gcnew String("cats");
strArray[6] = gcnew String("dogs");
strArray[7] = gcnew String("cats");
strArray[8] = gcnew String("dogs");
strArray[9] = gcnew String("cats");
bool found = false;
int index;
bool doThis = true;
String ^ text = u8"I have two dogs, three notdogs, also dogsikong, 5dogs, -dogs. DOGS, Dogs, DoGs, 33DoGs00";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
{
    int index = 0;
    while ((index = text->ToLower()->IndexOf(strArray[i]->ToLower(), index)) != -1)
    {
        doThis = true;
        // is there one more char?
        if (index + strArray[i]->Length < text->Length)
        {
            if (Char::IsLetter(text[index+strArray[i]->Length]))
                doThis = false;
        }
        // is there previous char?
        if (index > 0)
        {
            if (Char::IsLetter(text[index - 1]))
                doThis = false;
        }
        if (doThis)
            text = text->Substring(0, index) + strArray[i + 1] +
            text->Substring(index + strArray[i]->Length);
        Debug::WriteLine(text);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Of course it is still not so quick version. Quick version wrote David Yaw.

Comment: Have you tried using threads ?

Comment: No... I didn't hear about threads before. I'm starting programming. This is my first bigger application and the biggest problem.

Comment: "_But this is working for endlessly_" why your `for loop` iterates till 9999999?

Comment: Don't use string, but use something like `StringBuilder`, which features in-place modification.

Comment: Yes I had also idea to use `StringBuilder` or any other mutable something. But how can I get information if there is "dogs" or "adogs", "dogsss"? In `StringBuilder` i don't have any search method or even substring.
FirstStep - because 9999999 is my number of elements. I fixed array<String^>(10);.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a much better way to do this, rather than blindly checking each of one million replacement strings. Let .Net hash the strings, and have it do the checking that way.

If we receive the find & replace strings as a Dictionary, we can use .Net's hash lookups to find the strings that we need to replace.

If we step through each character in the string, it might be the beginning of a 5-character 'search for' string, or the beginning of a 4-character 'search for' string, etc, or it might not be part of a 'search for' string at all, in which case it'll get copied to the output directly. If we do find a 'search for' string, we'll write the replacement to the output, and mark the appropriate number of input characters as consumed.

Based on your description, it appears you want a case-insensitive comparison when searching for strings. You can use case-sensitive or -insensitive, just specify whatever you like when you construct the `Dictionary`.

```
String^ BigFindReplace(
    String^ originalString, 
    Dictionary<String^, String^>^ replacementPairs)
{
    // First, get the lengths of all the 'search for' strings in the replacement pairs.
    SortedSet<int> searchForLengths;
    for each (String^ searchFor in replacementPairs->Keys)
    {
        searchForLengths.Add(searchFor->Length);
    }

    // Searching for an empty string isn't valid: remove length zero, if it's there.
    searchForLengths.Remove(0);

    StringBuilder result;

    // Step through the input string. For each character:
    // A) See if the character is the beginning of one of the 'search for' strings.
    //    If so, then insert the 'replace with' string into the output buffer.
    //    Skip over this character and the rest of the 'search for' string that we found.
    // B) If it's not the beginning of a 'search for' string, copy it to the output buffer.

    for(int i = 0; i < originalString->Length; i++)
    {
        bool foundSomething = false;
        int foundSomethingLength = 0;
        for each (int len in searchForLengths.Reverse())
        {
            if (i > (originalString->Length - len))
            {
                // If we're on the last 4 characters of the string, we can ignore 
                // all the 'search for' strings that are 5 characters or longer.
                continue;
            }

            String^ substr = originalString->Substring(i, len);

            String^ replaceWith;
            if (replacementPairs->TryGetValue(substr, replaceWith))
            {
                // We found the section of the input string that we're looking at in our 
                // 'search for' list! Inser the 'replace with' into the output buffer.
                result.Append(replaceWith);
                foundSomething = true;
                foundSomethingLength = len;
                break; // don't try to find more 'search for' strings.
            }
        }

        if(foundSomething)
        {
            // We found & already inserted the replacement text. Just increment 
            // the loop counter to skip over the rest of the characters of the 
            // found 'search for' text.

            i += (foundSomethingLength - 1); // "-1" because the for loop has its own "+1".
        }
        else
        {
            // We didn't find any of the 'search for' strings, 
            // so this is a character that just gets copied.
            result.Append(originalString[i]);
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

My test app:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ text = "I have two dogs, three notdogs, also dogsikong, 5dogs, -dogs. DOGS, Dogs, DoGs, 33DoGs00";

    Dictionary<String^, String^>^ replacementPairs = 
        gcnew Dictionary<String^, String^>(StringComparer::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    replacementPairs->Add("dogs", "cats");
    replacementPairs->Add("pigs", "cats");
    replacementPairs->Add("mice", "cats");
    replacementPairs->Add("rats", "cats");
    replacementPairs->Add("horses", "cats");

    String^ outText = BigFindReplace(text, replacementPairs);

    Debug::WriteLine(outText);

    String^ text2 = "I have two dogs, three notpigs, also miceikong, 5rats, -dogs. RATS, Horses, DoGs, 33DoGs00";
    String^ outText2 = BigFindReplace(text, replacementPairs);

    Debug::WriteLine(outText2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
I have two cats, three notcats, also catsikong, 5cats, -cats. cats, cats, cats, 33cats00
I have two cats, three notcats, also catsikong, 5cats, -cats. cats, cats, cats, 33cats00
```

## Edit: Whole words only

OK, so we need to substitute whole words only. To do that, I wrote a helper method to split a string into words & nonwords. (This is different from the built-in String::Split method: String::Split doesn't return the delimiters, and we need them here.)

Once we have an array of strings, where every string is either a word or a bunch of non-word characters (e.g., separators, whitespace, etc.), then we can run each of those through the Dictionary. Because we're doing a whole word at a time, not just a single letter at a time, this is more efficient.

```
array<String^>^ SplitIntoWords(String^ input)
{
    List<String^> result;
    StringBuilder currentWord;
    bool currentIsWord = false;

    for each (System::Char c in input)
    {
        // Words are made up of letters. Word separators are made up of 
        // everything else (numbers, whitespace, punctuation, etc.)
        bool nextCharIsWord = Char::IsLetter(c);

        if(nextCharIsWord != currentIsWord)
        {
            if(currentWord.Length > 0)
            {
                result.Add(currentWord.ToString());
                currentWord.Clear();
            }
            currentIsWord = nextCharIsWord;
        }

        currentWord.Append(c);
    }

    if(currentWord.Length > 0)
    {
        result.Add(currentWord.ToString());
        currentWord.Clear();
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}

String^ BigFindReplaceWords(
    String^ originalString, 
    Dictionary<String^, String^>^ replacementPairs)
{
    StringBuilder result;

    // First, separate the input string into an array of words & non-words.
    array<String^>^ asWords = SplitIntoWords(originalString);

    // Go through each word & non-word that came out of the split. If a word or 
    // non-word is in the replacement list, add the replacement to the output. 
    // Otherwise, add the word/nonword to the output.

    for each (String^ word in asWords)
    {
        String^ replaceWith;
        if (replacementPairs->TryGetValue(word, replaceWith))
        {
            result.Append(replaceWith);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(word);
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

My test app:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ text = "I have two dogs, three notdogs, also dogsikong, 5dogs, -dogs. DOGS, Dogs, DoGs, 33DoGs00";

    array<String^>^ words = SplitIntoWords(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < words->Length; i++)
    {
        Debug::WriteLine("words[{0}] = '{1}'", i, words[i]);
    }

    Dictionary<String^, String^>^ replacementPairs = 
        gcnew Dictionary<String^, String^>(StringComparer::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    replacementPairs->Add("dogs", "cats");
    replacementPairs->Add("pigs", "cats");
    replacementPairs->Add("mice", "cats");
    replacementPairs->Add("rats", "cats");
    replacementPairs->Add("horses", "cats");

    String^ outText = BigFindReplaceWords(text, replacementPairs);

    Debug::WriteLine(outText);

    String^ text2 = "I have two dogs, three notpigs, also miceikong, 5rats, -dogs. RATS, Horses, DoGs, 33DoGs00";
    String^ outText2 = BigFindReplaceWords(text2, replacementPairs);

    Debug::WriteLine(outText2);

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
words[0] = 'I'
words[1] = ' '
words[2] = 'have'
words[3] = ' '
words[4] = 'two'
words[5] = ' '
words[6] = 'dogs'
words[7] = ', '
words[8] = 'three'
words[9] = ' '
words[10] = 'notdogs'
words[11] = ', '
words[12] = 'also'
words[13] = ' '
words[14] = 'dogsikong'
words[15] = ', 5'
words[16] = 'dogs'
words[17] = ', -'
words[18] = 'dogs'
words[19] = '. '
words[20] = 'DOGS'
words[21] = ', '
words[22] = 'Dogs'
words[23] = ', '
words[24] = 'DoGs'
words[25] = ', 33'
words[26] = 'DoGs'
words[27] = '00'
I have two cats, three notdogs, also dogsikong, 5cats, -cats. cats, cats, cats, 33cats00
I have two cats, three notpigs, also miceikong, 5cats, -cats. cats, cats, cats, 33cats00
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. Yes I can use dictionary and I will. Thanks. Unfortunatelly your code is not what I wanted - Output should be:

'I have two cats, three notpigs, also miceikong, 5cats, -cats. cats, cats, cats, 33cats00'

This is big difference

Comment: Why are "notpigs" and "miceikong" not substituted? Please explain your substitution rules.

Comment: Because I want to substitute only "exact words". If before or after "word" is any other letter I don't want to substitute it. List of prohibition letters is in `notAllowed` variable. Sorry, I also learning english language :). So if before or after "word_to_replace" is any of this characters: `aąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoópqrsśtuvwxyzźżAĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPQRSŚTUVWXYZŹŻёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ` I don't want to do substitution.
2dogs -> 2cats,   adogs -> adogs

Comment: You want to substitute whole words only. In that case, rather than having a list of 'these characters make up a word, so don't substitute if you see one', have a list of 'these characters separate words'. Then instead of stepping though the string character-by-characters, split the entire string into words, based on word separators, and step through word-by-word.

Comment: But in my list of 'these characters make up a word, so don't substitute if you see one' also is (for example) character "o" which is also in "dogs". How it will be working for words like: "dogs", "odogs", "dogso", "doogs" and other? Only first "dogs" must be "cats". By your description I understood that "dogs" will be "d"+"gs" and it will not be (unfortunatelly) "cats".

Comment: You need to reverse it: Don't split on "word characters" (such as "o"), split on "word *separator* characters", such as whitespace. "dogs" will stay as "dogs", and then you can substitute using the dictionary.

Comment: Ok... I understand now. It is a brilliant idea. I don't know yet if it solves all my problems or not. Write me only: why this is not working:

 `array<String^>^ separators = {"dogs", "three"};
 array<String^>^ separated = text->Split(separators);`

Comment: The String::Split method returns an array of strings, but that array doesn't include the separators. Also, I wouldn't recommend splitting on full words like "dogs": If you truely have a million of these things, that will be quite impractical. You're going to need a custom splitter method.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz See edit. Hopefully that solves it for you.

Comment: all of this word-separators I have in base (for now .txt base) so I don't need write them all to source code. So should I create my own splitter method? I have long way to go. EDIT: ok... I am looking now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues in your code the may cause problems but main logical error is:

`while (found = text->Contains(strArray[i]))`

should be

`while (found == text->Contains(strArray[i]))`

Since `==` is the comparison operator while `=` is an assignment operator. So you are always assigning, therefore your while loop in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... No?

```
while (found == text->Contains(strArray[i]))
```

is for comparison. But I didn't compute `found` before. So I calculate found in while and checking if it is true. It is allowed.

```
while (found = text->Contains(strArray[i]))
```

is exactly what:

```
found = text->Contains(strArray[i])
while (found==true)
```

At least in normal C++ it is working. Here I don't have problem with this also.

Answer (score 0):

Пётр Васильевич, a few suggestions:

1. Replace Substring(x, 1) with Char[x].
2. Throw away your `notAllowed` string and use .NET's [Char.IsLetter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or at least break out of your `for()` loops when you set `doThis = false;`
3. If you need a substring from `index` to the end of string, you don't need to calculate the length; just use a form with one parameter: [public string Substring(int startIndex)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
4. Don't use `text->Contains()`; you need to call `text->IndexOf()` anyway, just compare that index to `-1`.
5. 10 million words??? There aren't that many in English and Russian combined!
6. Use two-parameters form of [String.IndexOf Method (Char, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), to specify where to start the search (from the position of the previously found word), to avoid searching the beginning of the string over and over. Something like that:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 9999999; i += 2) 
   {
       int index = 0;
       while ((index = text->IndexOf(strArray[i], index)) != -1)
       {
           doThis = true;
           // is there one more char?
           if (index + strArray[i]->Length < text->Length) 
           {
               if(Char.IsLetter(text->Char[strArray[i]->Length]))
                   doThis = false;
           }
           // is there previous char?
           if (index > 0)
           {
               if (Char.IsLetter(text->Char[index - 1]))
                   doThis = false;
           }
           if (doThis)
               text = text->Substring(0, index) + strArray[i + 1] +
                      text->Substring(index + strArray[i]->Length);
       }
   }
   ```
7. In your `while()` loop, collect the indexes of the found strings into an array, then do all replacement of the same word in one pass. That is particularly useful if there are multiple occurances of the same word in `text`.

Comment: Thanks for all. There is not only English and Russian. Fortunately the base I am doing without any mistakes :)

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz - please check just added items #6 and #7. Also please let me know how your time has improved with these suggestions :)

Comment: It will be hard to say, because all what I wrote in this topic is only small part of bigger project. But both - 6 and 7 are useful and much quicker than my project. I will add comment here in some days when I will discover it.

Comment: When I add only your changes everything what was executing in 19 minutes now is executing in 11 seconds. I think especially because of `isLetter` function. With also **David Yaw** changes everything what was executing in 15 minutes now is executing in 1 sencond. :) Thanks. I added both of changes to many different parts of code.